# i want to access to array's value by using parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters

Nice to meet you. It's my first time asking a question. I'm glad I found this community.

I'm learning javascript and wrote this function but the error keeps coming out.
error says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined`
but I don't know why! `toDos` is an array has text, id.
When i change `a` to some random number, the error doesn't show up.
Why can't I access `toDos.id` by using parameter?

```
function resetId() {
  let a = 0;
  while (a !== toDos.length) {
    toDos[a - 1].id = a;
    a = a + 1;
  }
  console.log(`끝났어 ${a}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach` loop to simplify iteration.

```
function resetId(toDos = []) {
  toDos.forEach((todo, index) => {
    localStorage.getItem("id");
    todo.id = index;
    console.log(todo)
  });
}
```

resetId([{id: 0, name: 'something'}, {id: 0, name: 'something'}])

```js
   function resetId(toDos = []) {
      toDos.forEach((todo, index) => {
        // comment localStorage for demo
        //localStorage.getItem("id");
        todo.id = index;
        console.log(todo)
      });
    }

resetId([{id: null, name: 'something'}, {id: null, name: 'something'}])
```

Comment: i forgot using forEach! thank you for that, but i'm still wondering why i can't access to toDos.id by using my way! could you explain to me please?

Comment: How you are calling `resetId`. I think issue with data. Data should be array of object